# Can I create virtual network address which routes to port on my machine?

Tags: networking, lan, hardware-virtualization

I would like to create a virtual address on my LAN such that it looks like a separate machine and when I connect from my host machine or other machines it actually routes traffic to a specific port on the host machine.

Comment: What if an App and the VPN access to it use numerous unrelated ports.  What you want seems complicated to me.  What problem are you trying to solve

Comment: I have an SMB server application. I want to be able to connect to this application as an SMB share, but windows has restrictions on which ports can be used for SMB (port 445 and some other port I can't remember). Port 445 is reserved for the host machines SMB, so it would be nice to expose a separate IP where port 445 routes to a different port on the host machine which is served by my app. NOTE: I may end up having multiple SMB apps, so hacking around to use the other port is a not an option.

Comment: I connect 2 machines by SMB on the SMB port to the same files on the host. It does not seem to be hampered in any way.

Comment: That's not my use case. I have multiple SMB **servers** (not clients). For instance, I am working on an application which exposes Azure blob storage as an SMB share so you can browse and interact with it like a normal file system. I am using this library as the basis of my application: https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary.